# Truncated the whole text instead of just letters

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[What I'm trying to achieve. Image sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwL8U.png)

Hi Guys I'm still learning and trying to truncate a long text but with few conditions.
Let's say I have an array of 5 words, if the text is too long, it will need to truncate the text to accommodate the width of the container. But I wanted it to cut the whole word instead of just the letters. As example object of [one, two, three, four, five]

One, two, three, ... 2 (counter) I want this

One, two, three, fou ... 1 (counter) I don't want this

Below is what I have tried but I'm not sure where to go next also to make the counter dynamic based on truncated text number instead of an array length.

```
function App() {
  const numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

  const testStyle = {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    background: "#D0D0D0",
    padding: "6px 8px",
    width: "150px",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  };

  const truncatedStyle = {
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    overflow: "hidden",
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={testStyle}>
        <div style={truncatedStyle}>
          {numbers.map((n, i) => (
            <span>
              {n}
              {i === 4 ? "" : ", "}
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: "black", color: "white", padding: "2px 4px" }}
        >
          {numbers.length}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is you can use `useRef` and get those spans width, then check it
in a variable if it is greater than `150px`. if no the add the span, if yes then add `, ...` then add the span width to the variable.

Comment: Ahh, I see that gives me an idea to check and detect the width dynamically if user resizing,  But how to detect the truncated word and cut it completely rather than having a few letters.

Comment: that is why i mentioned there as you are taking words inside a span u can just not add the `span` which come beyond the width and add `, ...`. which will not add half words.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `**function App()**` using Vanilla Javascript you can achieve the same result in the form of String and then through String Interpolation you can render it on the HTML as going by Best Coding Practices all the logic part must be concluded in JS and HTML should be used only for view/rendering the data.

**Example -**

```
function App() {
  var s = "";
  var c = 0;
  const numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
  for(var i =0 ; i< numbers.length;i++){
    i>2 ? c++ : s = s+numbers[i]+", ";
  }
  return numbers.length > 3 ? s+".." + c : s;
}
```